# why parent is not working in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me why `parent` function is not working properly ?

here is my code

https://jsbin.com/gefacenefi/edit?html,js,output

```
 $(function () {

        $('.add').click(function () {
            $('.item').parent('li.nn').css('color', 'red');
        });

    });
```

**Expected output**
this text to be red

```
<li class="nn">bhiooo</li>
```

Comment: well I see no `.item` that is a child of the `li.nn`

Comment: `li.nn` is not an ancestor of `.item`.

Comment: Why don't you simply red the class. `$('.nn').css('color', 'red');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do the following:

```
$(function () {
    $('.add').click(function () {
      $('.item').parent().siblings('li.nn').css('color', 'red');
    });
});
```

Also you are not closing your `li` element properly. The structure should be like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <title>JS Bin</title>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <button class="add">filler</button>
   <div>
      <ul>
         <li class="nn">bhiooo</li>
         <li class="m">hello22
            <ul class="item">
                <li class="abc">123</li>
                <li class="pp">12</li>
                <li class="abc">78</li>
                <li class="ac">13</li>
                </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you got a typo. Is `parent` not `parents`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a parent of a different node. Try this

```
$('.add').click(function () {
  $('.item').parent().siblings('li.nn').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ul `.item` is not under `.nn`.

Change the HTML, or adapt you JS

`$('.item').parent().prev('li.nn').css('color', 'red');`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$('.add').click(function () {
  $('.item').parents().find('.nn').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/nq9tzafz/

I think it should helps you